# How to correctly use a button in a listbox itemtemplate / datatemplate?

Tags: c#, silverlight, styles, datatemplate

I have a Silverlight application that displays a list of items in a `ListBox`. Each item represents a different 'page' of my application so I have a style that is applied to the `ItemContainerStyle` property that looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="navigationItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,3"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <!-- code omitted --!> 
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="contentBorder"
                            Background="{StaticResource navigationHighlightBrush}" 
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            Opacity="0"/>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="content"
                                    Margin="10,5"
                                    Content="{Binding}" 
                                    Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The style is very simple. It simply displays the `Border` when the `ListBoxItem`'s visual state is equal to 'Selected'. Notice that the content is hosted by a `ContentControl` as I want to be able to change the `Foreground` property when the item is in the 'Selected' state.

This works brilliantly as can be seen by the screenshot below:

[image]

Now I want the selected item to invoke navigation so the idea I had was to create a `DataTemplate` that sets the content of each item to a `HyperLinkButton`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="navigationListBoxItemTemplate">
    <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding}" 
                     Background="Transparent"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now this doesn't work as the `ItemTemplate` hosts it's content in a `ContentControl` rather than a `ContentPresenter` so I have had to update the `ListBoxItem` template to use a `ContentPresenter` instead.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="content" Margin="10,5"/>
```

I now get the following result:

[image]

When I click on the `HyperLinkButton` the `ListBoxItem` is now no longer selected (I can click just outside the `HyperLinkButton` and the `ListBoxItem` becomes selected). What I really want is for the `ListBoxItem` to become selected when the `HyperLinkButton` is clicked. The  `HyperLinkButton` has no concept of selection so I cannot bind to the `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property.

**Note:** The actual navigation works perfectly, the problem is purely with the appearance of the `ListBoxItems`.

**So my questions are:**

1. Can I make it so that when the `HyperLinkButton` is clicked, the `ListBoxItem` becomes selected like the first image?
2. I will also need some way of changing the foreground of the `HyperLinkButton` when it is selected as this is no longer done in the items template due to me swapping the `ContentControl` fro a `ContentPresenter`.

**Note:** I could probably solve this problem by binding the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` to my viewModel and handling the navigation there negating the requirement to have a `HyperLinkButton` hosted by each `ListBoxItem` but I am interested in knowing if it is possible using styles and templates to achieve my desired result.

**Update**

I have tried a couple of things to try and resolve this but so far have been unsuccessful. The first thing I tried was applying a new style to the `HyperLinkButton` control in my `DataTemplate` which essentially removes all of the default look and feel from the control but my application still behaves in the way described above.

The second thing I tried was setting the `IsHitTestVisible` property to false. This allows me to click 'through' the `HyperLinkbutton` and select the `ListBoxItem` but this means that the navigation is now no longer invoked.

Comment: Hi, Can you try using the NavigationService.Navigate(Uri) method within your listBox_SelectionChanged() event handler ?

Comment: @prthrokz - I don't have a problem invoking the navigation method. My problem is purely with the presentation of the `ListBoxItem`s.

Comment: What my intention was that you can practically omit adding the HyperLinkButton because what I understood from the post is that you had to switch to it because you wanted a navigation to be invoked.

Comment: Thanks, in answer to your comment, yes I could use your suggestion. As per my note I have a solution which is basically the same as your suggestion except it uses MVVM. I was just curious if what I was trying was possible seeing as it is 90% implemented.

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42249449/919272). It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListBoxItem is not selected because the Button (whatever type it is) marks the MouseLeftButtonDown event as Handled. Therefore the required event does not bubble up to the parent ListBoxItem.

Evidently, your ListBoxItem is getting focus from the click (I assume that is the border in your final image), so this must happen regardless.

Under the covers, the ListBoxItem will have a standard LeftMouseButtonDown event handler set up to deal with Selection, and it must have a call to AddHandler to deal with setting focus.

---

You can achieve something similar by adding your own handler for the event, like so:

```
 listboxitem.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MyMouseLeftButtonDownEventHandler), true);
```

The final parameter instructs the handler to handle handled events...

Attaching this handler I leave to you, but using a behavior is probably the most straight forward. You could event derive a type from Button and have it walk up the Visual Tree to find and select the ListBoxItem... The possibilities are endless.

Comment: In hindsight the fact that the event was already handled by the button should have been obvious. As mentioned in my question I actually had an alternative solution in place but the information was still useful to have. Thank you.