# Listbox SelectionChanged not working with Button in its ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selectionchanged

Code below does not work when I select item in listbox, do you happen to know why?

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Name="listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="selection_changed">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Button Height="90" Width="150" Template="{StaticResource cbutton}"/>                
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And template cbutton looks like this

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="cbutton" TargetType="Button">
            <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="3.5" BorderBrush="White">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkOrange" Offset="0.1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.85"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: "does not work" means what? What happens? Is there an error?

Comment: I checked whether it works by showing message like this `code` private void selection_changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("works?");            
        }`code`  but nothing is shown.

Comment: Did you try to use another control instead of a button in the datatemplate?

Comment: Yes, I did. I put textblock and it worked but I was wondering what's wrong with button that it behaves in unexpected way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectionChanged` event is not fired because the button is the control who captures the mouse click, not the `ListBox`.

You can set your event handler to the button's click event instead.

```
   <Button Height="90" Width="150" Click="myClickEventHandler"/>
```

Regardless, I recommend you to use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), instead of Code-Behind event handler.

you could set a command which will fire when the button's click and send the command the button's content for example

```
  <Button Name="myButton" Height="90" Width="150" Template="{StaticResource cbutton}">     
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomething}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=Content}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </Button>
```

ViewModel

```
DoSomething = new DelegateCommand<object>(content=> 
{
    // Do whatever you want 

});
```

If your not familar with MVVM, it will take some time to learn it, but it is definetly worth it :)

Comment: @user2396510 My apologies, that answer wasn't good, I upadted my answer

Comment: @user2396510 Unlike WinForms, WPF Events mechanism has a few sorts of events - events that go from the top most parent to the children and events that goes the opposite way. you can learn more about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events)

Comment: I barely know MVVM but it seems to be worth to learn it. Thank you.

Comment: @user2396510 I HIGHLY recommand you to learn it. it may be a little difficult to get it at first, but once you do - you understand it's true power. I posted some good links about MVVM in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874258/wpf-adding-a-combobox-to-a-datagrid-or-list-view-based-on-different-db-tables/18874582#18874582)

Comment: Had same issue.  Instead of using a 'Command' object from the button, I set binding on the Button.Tag property (to the same thing I was binding to the Button.Content) and trapped the click event in my ViewModel (using Caliburn Micro for my MVVM).  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the PreviewMouseDown event handler on the ListBoxItem:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItemsSource}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown"
                             Handler="ItemOnPreviewMouseDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>


    private void ItemOnPreviewMouseDown(
        object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ListBoxItem) sender).IsSelected = true;
    }
```